# Authlib with Azure AD - claims validation error for "iss" claim

Tags: python, azure, authlib

I used to use `Flask-OAuthlib`, but since that is not supported anymore, I've switched to [Authlib](https://github.com/lepture/authlib) with Flask. I am using the OpenID Connect support with the OpenID configuration link (pretty much the same example as this one: https://github.com/authlib/demo-oauth-client/blob/master/flask-google-login/app.py). It works perfectly with Google, however, I'm running in a problem with Azure AD. I've set everything up, the flow runs and Azure does the whole logging in and asking permissions. However, once that passes, Authlib itself throws an error in the `client.parse_id_token()` method while validating the `iss` claim from the returned ID token.

The error that is raised is `authlib.jose.errors.InvalidClaimError: invalid_claim: Invalid claim "iss"`. Using Flask's debugger and reading the source code for `_validate_claim_value()` function I've confirmed that it is trying to compare `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/v2.0'` to the same URL but with the `{tenant}` replaced with the fixed GUID (as per docs on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens).

My guess is that my app should do the replacement here somehow and then let the validation fly, however, I am not sure how to do it. The question is: is there a good way in Authlib that I could do this, prior to claims being validated?

P.S.: I've seen and am aware of [loginpass](https://github.com/authlib/loginpass), but would like to explore first using stock Authlib since this is an existing application and I would not like to mess that much with blueprints if at all possible.

Answer (score -1):

I would not be able to comment on Authlib since that is a 3rd party library. But yes you need to have the iss claim in [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/v2.0](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenantid%7D/v2.0) format.

On that note, Microsoft provides [Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) for Python](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python) as official SDK to integrate with [Microsoft Identity platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview) (includes Azure AD).